# How to find Vout of the circuit?

Tags: voltage, diodes

For the circuit shown below, diodes have these parameters : RD=infinit, Vy=0.6 V.
In forward bias diodes , V=0.7 V .
V1=10 V , V2=-5 V
Vo =?

[image]

I don't know if my solution is correct. Please provide any suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @DanielGiesbrecht It clearly is, but he has made an attempt and showed his work.

Comment: @BlairFonville fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what i can see you made 2 faults

First of all,  you switched from KOhm to Ohm. (they differ a factor 1000)

Secondly, I dont think that is the right way to compute the current through a resistor-diode-resistor circuit. This is what i think:

Name the voltage just above the 9k resistor X. Now the current that flows through the first resistor is equal to 10v-(X+0,7v)/1kOhm. The current that flows through the last resistor is X/9kOhm. The part of the circuit we look at is a series circuit so there must be an equal amount of current flowing at any place.

This gives us 10-(X+0.7)/1000=X/9000 <=> 90-9X-0.7*9=X <=> 83.7=10X <=> 8.37v

So yes you got the same result as me but i think you are going to make mistakes when the circuits are bigger because your way of calculating the result is really tricky and doesn't work all the time.

Comment: thanks a lot                                                                                    Yeah you're right. I should have written miliAmper instead of Amper and your way of calculating the voltage, looks clearer.                                  In this exercise, there are given the diode parameters: RD=infinit and Vy=0.6 V , but I've not used them. Is that a mistake?

Comment: What does RD=inf and Vy=0.6V mean? I dont think its something general because i never heard of those constants :D

Comment: I thought RD was the resistance in the other flow direction but i dont know what Vy is

Comment: @Rik I found that: In order to “turn on” and conduct current in the forward direction, a diode requires a certain amount of positive voltage to be applied across it. The typical voltage required to turn the diode on is called the forward voltage (VF). It might also be called either the cut-in voltage(Vy) or on-voltage.

Comment: @greenland yeah that was also my first thought but there is also a 0.7v value given and most of the time the VF value is 0.7v so i took this value and ignored the 0.6v :D